# Merge styles - How to use vendor prefixes

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I'm using this library `@uifabric/merge-styles` from `office-ui-fabric`. My question is how to use vendor prefixes inside `mergeStyleSets`?

Example `-webkit-filter`:

```
import { mergeStyleSets } from '@uifabric/merge-styles'

mergeStyleSets({ 
  webkitFilter: 'blur(5px)', // Error! No Typescript definition.
})
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

[Merge Styles Library](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/tree/master/packages/merge-styles)

It looks like there is no Typescript definitions for it
[IRawStyleBase.ts](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/merge-styles/src/IRawStyleBase.ts)

**Addition to @Vitalie Braga answer:**

This is temporary solution if you are using `Typescript` project:

```
const foo = mergeStyleSets({
  root: [
    {
      backgroundColor: '#f00',
      ...({ '-webkit-filter': 'blur(5px)' } as any)
    },
  ]
})
```

[Issues Page - Git OFFICE UI FABRIC](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/11473#issuecomment-566262114)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@uifabric/merge-styles` library has smarts about automatic vendor prefixing for you but the only issue with that is that the rules that are auto-prefixed today are limited to [just one](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/1b9405b3b64839975e16ee1fad04d7868d9e3b99/packages/merge-styles/src/transforms/prefixRules.ts#L3-L5): `user-select`. I would advise you go and submit an issue in their github repo [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues) and either ask if new rules can be added or ask how to handle this situation.

From a deeper investigation looks like they have some vendor specific support but is very limited in [IRawStyleBase.ts](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/4ed3197a88eb697bb4238fbe31e0c4b4f6678c77/packages/merge-styles/src/IRawStyleBase.ts#L283-L308). Those rules will automatically be transformed into vendor rules.

So to answer your questions if you are using a TS project there is no way you can specify something that is not compatible with the `IRawStyleBase` interface but if you are using a js script you can probably try your luck as I did in this [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mergestylesvendorprefix-ikcox) and it looks like the filter get's through but nothing else.

Comment: I read about automatic vendor prefixing from motivation section here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/tree/master/packages/merge-styles#motivation but it confused me how it works. Now, i got it. Yes, i'm using TS project so i need to open issue. Thank you for answer and working example.